# If the bass moves chromatically is any chord progression possible?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

Let say there is a chord progression something like

(C Major key)

C - Bb7 - F/A

From Bb7 (SubV7) which would probably go to A.
Will it be ok to resolute only the bass to A and go to a different chord that has the A note I could use for the bass and go to a whole different chord from A ?
(Something like D7/A , F7/A ?)

Comment: *Anything* is *always* OK, if it sounds good to you!

Comment: @topomorto I'm not in front of the keyboard so I didn't try it yet. But I'm asking it from a theoretical view

Comment: *I'm not in front of the keyboard* - Fair enough :) - though your instrument will be able to answer this question better than we can! When I say 'Anything is always OK', that's perhaps a simplification - in some particular musical styles, some harmonic motions might be unexpected. So if you can specify a particular genre, we can give advice from that point of view. But in general it is true to say that even from a theoretical point you *can* do anything; anything is *possible*; all that's left are subjective judgements about whether it sounds good.

Comment: A quote we often use around here: "Music theory is created to DESCRIBE the way in which pieces are written, not PRESCRIBE how music should be written." Did someone tell you that music theory is there to tell you what you can and can't do? To quote RATM, "whoever told you that is your enemy".

Comment: @topomorto - why, oh why, don't people understand not the theory itself, but what *theory* IS?

Comment: @Tim because not everyone knows about this site yet :)

Comment: @topomorto - on a serious note - people who *use* this site still don't appear to understand...

Comment: @Tim music theory is often taught from a particular point of view, and with a particular set of assumptions - understandably so, as people want to get on and start using it. But if you do that, you have to at some point take a step back and see what it is (and isn't) that you've learned - perhaps people don't do that, and perhaps 'educators' are sometimes also guilty of not encouraging that early enough. I think that's one reason I like the "why don't we give all notes the names of animals" kind of questions - they are an opportunity to take that step back.

Comment: @topomorto - good points. One of the many reasons why I leave 'theory' until students can play a fair bit, *and* know their instruments - both very different skills - is that by then, they've usually assimilated some theory unconsciously, and the eyes usually open wide and 'so that's why it works' is uttered. Up till then, the why isn't as important as the how - to the majority. There's always an exception, though, and it's usually one who goes away with a bit of theory, and next lesson, has formulated the next lot - inaccurately! It don't half waste a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

You ask 'will it be o.k?'

The biggest point is 'what will happen if you do?'

The main consequences will be : it sounds great and everyone will love it; it will grate and sound horrible and no-one will like it; something in between.

You will not lose a go, or be locked in jail.

Often, the bass notes will reflect the chord at the time, rather than vice versa, which is your proposition. And here, you suggest other chords with that A note contained within.

So, yes, it'll work. It won't be what the listener expects - C > Bb > ? more often *does*  > F. But isn't that one of the points in music. The unexpected. 'I didn't see/hear that coming'. More to the point is - now you're out on a bit of a limb, let's see how you get back home safely.

The biggest criterion is how it sounds - to you *and* the listener. The 'rules', aka 'theory', as we keep banging on about, will try to explain what's happening, to help future readers. Guidelines, maps, if you like. But if everyone stuck to the well-trodden route, nothing new would ever get discovered.

EDIT: you ask if *any* chord will fit. Probably not *any* chord, but certainly any containing that A.